# Compare beginning of strings of a list with a whitelist

Tags: python, performance, list, python-3.x, compare

I want to compare a list with a whitelist. What I do now is the following:

```
>>> whitelist = ("one", "two")
>>> my_list = ["one", "two foo", "two bar", "three"]
>>> for item in my_list:
...     if not item.startswith(whitelist):
...         print(item)
three
```

Is there a more efficient/"better" way to do it?

Comment: This is pretty much the way you do it -- If you want to test that the elements match the whitelist exactly, then it's a bit different, and you might recast as a comprehension depending on what you want to do with the items ... But otherwise, this is the right idea.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks, that's a fine comment to confirm the idea.

Comment: Do you want to print them or collect them?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The print statement was just an example and isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
>>> [item for item in my_list if not item.startswith(whitelist)]
['three']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print '\n'.join([item for item in my_list if not item.startswith(whitelist)])
```